# Как получить рекомендованные товары WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как правильно составить запрос к `WP_Query` на получение рекомендованных товаров?

Comment: вам последние поступления нужны или всё таки рекомендованые к определённому товару?

Comment: Не понял вопроса... =) Нужны рекомендованные товары. В общем, уже разобрались, спасибо!

Comment: просто чеканули вы вывод товаров по таксономии featured, а это последние поступившие товары.

Comment: проверил, featured работает как рекомендуемые товары...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для WooCommerce версии 3.0 запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
        ),
    ),
);
$featured = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

[$array = wc_get_related_products( $product_id, $limit, $exclude_ids )](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_related_products/) , например.